# How remove whitespace on field in twig?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I try to print field value in a node--template.html.twig without whitespace.
This field is a select in admin page.

```
Location|Location 
Achat|Achat
```

This is how my value is print :

> {{ content.field_type }}

[image]

> field.html.twig :

```
{% for item in items %}
{{- item.content -}}
{%  endfor %}
```

I try some twig argument like

> {{content.field_type|trim}}

But when i print like this, it's empty.

So where are this whitespace ? same if i try to test the value in if else condition :

This doesn't work because of whitespace :

> {% if  content.field_type == "Achat" %}

This work :

> {% if  content.field_type|render|trim == "Achat" %}

So for test a value it's ok, but for print the value if i use

> {{content.field_type|render|trim}}

i got same result with whitespace.

So if someone can tell me where is add this whitespace and how remove this in twig.
I use the boostrap theme, but i don't see anything who add whitespace.

Comment: Have you tried using `spaceless`? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: Also you don't want to do checks on the render array, do it on the field itself via `node.field_type.value == 'Achat'`

Comment: Agree for the test, but for the print ? why whitespace ?

Comment: @Kevin about your comment please : could you develop a bit why /when checking on entity object over content render array ? e.g profile.some_field vs content.some_field ? my template say in comments :Use 'content' to print them all, or print a subset such as  'content.title'. Tks :)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds to me that you have a template, probably `field.html.twig` that is adding this space. You can enable the `twig` debug to see which templates' files are used.

Also, I think it's better to test the value on `node.field.value` instead of `content.field` as it's done for the rendering only.

Note that the twig operators as `{% for ... %}` also add spaces, so you should add `-` as well in there for e.g.:

```
{%- for item in items %}
{{ item.content }}
{%  endfor -%}
```

Comment: The template use is field.html.twig, i just add - in {%- for, but it's the same, whitespace always here... i agree for test the value to use node.field.value.

Comment: What is this hyphen doing? And why isn't this default behavior?

Comment: Ah! [Whitespace Control Modifier](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control). Gosh is this ugly. This really should be a global default.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many times and spaceless tag works pretty well.

Use the following syntax:

```
{% spaceless %}

  {{content.field_type}}

{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: i still got whitespace

Comment: I, too, was thoroughly disappointed.

Comment: Interesting enough, this worked for me for a separate project.

Comment: maybe you didn't clear the drupal cache?