# Remove trailing whitespace from a field

Tags: theming, 8, entities

Here is a slice of code from my twig template, which outputs the contents of some fields into a p tag:

```
<p>
    {{ content.field_story_program_name }},
    {{ content.field_story_relationship}},
    {{ content.field_story_city }}, 
    {{ content.field_story_state }}
</p>
```

The output on the page renders a trailing white space after each field's content, which I don't want (because it creates spaces before the commas):

> Local Head Start Program Provider , Head Start administrator , Los Angeles , CA

Things I've tried:

- Based on [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231282/how-remove-whitespace-on-field-in-twig), I checked my field.html.twig template to see if it's introducing spaces (it's not).
- Tried putting a - in the `{% endfor %}` on that field.html.twig template anyway to see if it would help: `{% endfor -%}` (it didn't).
- Put all of my values on one line in case a carriage return was being interpreted as whitespace (I think that was a Drupal 7 issue that I read) as in:
  `{{ content.field_story_first_name }} {{ content.field_story_last_name }}, {{ content.field_story_program_name }}, ...etc`
  But that didn't fix it
- Tried `{% spaceless %}` though I know it's just for spaces *between* tags and so of course that didn't end up helping
- Using the `|trim` Twig filter, which makes the entire value disappear and produces a rendering error. I suppose that *technically* solves the whitespace problem...  ;)

Can anyone help give me a clue? I would like to either

1. Find out where the extra space is coming from and turn it off there, or
2. Use the appropriate Twig filter to remove the space

Comment: Have you tried `|trim(side='right')` or perhaps `|raw|trim(side='right')` if your field contains markup? Are your field perhaps containing linebreaks? Try using `|replace({ "\n": "" })|trim(side='right')`

Comment: @Cyclonecode The fields themselves are simple "Text (plain)" field types with a format of "plain text", so I can't see where they could possibly be getting line breaks. I'm going to try all of your suggestions now, thanks.

Comment: **|trim(side='right')** produces a fatal php error "Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown argument "side" for filter "trim(character_mask)" in "themes/gesso/templates/node/node--story.html.twig" " even though it's written exactly like the documentation says to write it (https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/trim.html)

Comment: **|trim(' ', 'right')**  produces the kind of php error where you can still see the page rendered after the error text at the top.  "Warning: trim() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given "

Comment: **|raw|trim(side='right')** produces a fatal php error "Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown argument "side" for filter "trim(character_mask)"

Comment: **|replace({ "\n": "" })|trim(side='right')** produces the same fatal error "Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown argument "side" for filter "trim(character_mask)".  It really doesn't like the _side_ argument.

Comment: perhaps use google?

Comment: @Cyclonecode believe me, I googled for a loooooooong time before ever posting a question here. I wouldn't _dare_ to post a question without googling.

Comment: I think that **|trim** solutions aren't working because trim works directly on strings, according to the documentation, and I'm using a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, here is what finally worked: wrap every individual field in `{% spaceless %}` (not just the whole block) and use render and trim together.  Trim alone makes the variable disappear. Here's my markup:

```
<p>
  {% spaceless %}{{ content.field_story_program_name|render|trim }}{% endspaceless %},
  {% spaceless %}{{ content.field_story_relationship|render|trim }}{% endspaceless %},
  {% spaceless %}{{ content.field_story_city|render|trim }}{% endspaceless %}, 
  {{ content.field_story_state }}
</p>
```

Extra thanks to @Cyclonecode for giving me a variety of tricks to try.

Comment: This works for removing trailing slashes as well. You're genius @Leraa. {% spaceless %}{{ front|render|trim('/') }}{% endspaceless %}