# Twig whitespace controls have no effect on fields

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to iterate over a Paragraph field and apply a comma after each Paragraph item.

In the field template that outputs the Paragraph, I am trying:

```
{%- for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}
{% endfor -%}
```

This puts the comma out, but there is a ton of whitespace all over:

[image]

I have tried many whitespace control combinations and none seem to have any effect.

How can I remove this sort of behavior entirely? The paragraph field is an entity reference, that renders a view mode, so I don't want to install field delimeter plugin.

edit: Tried the solutions mentioned here:

[How remove whitespace on field in twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231282/how-remove-whitespace-on-field-in-twig)

and here:

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/whitespace-created-when-using-if-statements

as well as in the documentation.

The structure is as follows:

Node -> Paragraph field -> Paragraph (Entity) -> User Reference + Plain text field + rich text

In this context, only the user field is being rendered, and I want to put a comma at the end of each linked name.

Comment: You should provide the white space control combos u alrdy tried.

Comment: Is this paragraph field inside a view?

Comment: Nope, field on a node.

Comment: If you switch to the Bartik theme, does the same issue persist?

Answer (score 0):

Although the [whitespace control modifier](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control) is supposed to work for all `{{ … }}` prints, `{% … %}` statements and `{# … #}` comments I'd expect to make your sample work it needs to be put directly into the print like that:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{- item.content -}}{{- not loop.last ? ', ' -}}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively you could try to use the [`{% spaceless %}` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html). But again, I'd expect this only works right when placed inside the loop:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% spaceless %}
    {{ item.content }}{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}
  {% endspaceless %}
{% endfor %}
```

> As of Twig 1.38, use the [`|spaceless` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/spaceless.html) instead.